# I am trying to remove a certain string from a list having trouble

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
inventory = ['Sword','meat','meat']
```

Meat heals you so once you use it, it takes one away.  How would I take it away by using something like `inventory.remove('meat')`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  What do you mean by, "it takes one away"?

Answer (score 1):

> How would I take it away by using something like inventory.remove('meat')?

Yes, you are exactly correct. `inventory.remove('meat')` does what you want.

```
>>> inventory = ["sword", "meat", "meat"]
>>> inventory.remove("meat")
>>> inventory
['sword', 'meat']
```

Comment: I agree; this is definitely the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Per the help text (`help(list.remove)`, emphasis mine):

> `L.remove(value)` -- remove **first occurrence** of `value`

So there is no problem with your current code:

```
>>> l = ['sword', 'meat', 'meat']
>>> l.remove('meat')
>>> l
['sword', 'meat']
```

That being said, a much better implementation for your inventory would be a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) `{item: count}`:

```
>>> d = {'sword': 1, 'meat': 2}
>>> d['meat'] -= 1
>>> d
{'meat': 1, 'sword': 1}
```

You have to add extra checking (e.g. `if d['meat']:`) to ensure a non-zero count before subtracting, but this allows you to much more easily manage a large number of different items. You could simplify your code further with a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this example and it worked:

```
inventory = ['Sword','Meat','meat']

long_sentence = "Meat heals you so once you use it it takes one away"
sent_list = long_sentence.split()

print "[before:]",inventory

for i in inventory:
    if i in long_sentence:
        inventory.remove(i)

print "[after:]",inventory
```

I think you are having problem with comparing capitalized `"Meat"` and the small letter `"meat"` work in the list